# How Can I Structure My Code So I Don't Hard Code Values?

Tags: c#

I have a function that does a data lookup and returns a value:

```
public int LastBalance(int meterNumber)
{
    // Return value from data access layer
    return dal.GetLastBalance(meterNumber);
}
```

For a specific meterNumber value I want to return 0 (zero).

Is this OK?

```
public int LastBalance(int meterNumber)
{
    if(meterNumber = 999)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        // Return value from data access layer
        return dal.GetLastBalance(meterNumber);
    }
 }
```

Is there a way I can do this without hardcoding a value (999 in this case)? What if in the future I have other "magic numbers" that I need to return specific values for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your web.config or app.config to define these values, then read those values from config file and return them, example

Create custom class which will read values from config and return you real value

```
public class MeterValues
{
    public static Dictionary<int, int> meterList =  new Dictionary<int, int>();
    public static int ReturnValue(int meterValue)
    {
        if (meterList.Count == 0)
            LoadValues();
        return meterList.ContainsKey(meterValue) ? meterList[meterValue] : dal.GetLastBalance(meterNumber);
    }
    public static void LoadValues()
   {
      string[] _cValues = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Meter.Values"].ToString().Split(',');
      foreach(string val in _cValues)
      {
        string[] _param = val.Split(':');
        meterList.Add(Convert.ToInt32(_param[0]), Convert.ToInt32(_param[1]);
      }
   }
}
```

So your code would look like this

```
public int LastBalance(int meterNumber)
{
    return MeterValues.ReturnValue(meterNumber);
 }
```

Your config file should have key

```
<add key="Meter.Values" value="121:12,999:0,837:12" />
```

so for value 123 it will return 12 for value 999 will return 0, and for any other value that is not in the list will call your dal method.

This can be also don via DataBase, store values and just append them in LoadValues() method

Comment: Nice, very clean. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

You could put the value in a config file.  You could also create a custom config section and store a set of values, and then reference that in your code.

If you do hardcode it, store it as a const named "IGNORED_METER_NUMBER" or something similar, which will make your code much more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your own configuration file structure, like this:

```
<config>
<mappings>
  <mapping from="999" to="0"/>
  <mapping from="123" to="456"/>
</mappings>
</config>
```

In your code ask if the "from" attributes of the mappings contain the key x. If so, replace with the "to" attribute value of that entry.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few scenarios you could follow here. The mentioned config file method is pretty good. Also, you could pull the numbers from a database if you are connecting to one. If you know that you will be returning zero any time one of these values comes up, you could put them in a list and do this:

```
if(excludeList.Contains(meterNumber))
{
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [use configuration files](http://generally.wordpress.com/2007/09/27/using-appconfig-for-user-defined-runtime-parameters/) to store values, either as a file resource, or in app(or web).config.

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understood your question, so will try to give a useful response. Somewhere, soon or later you have to declare hardcoded value. It can be data read from `ConfigFile`, it can be `Constants` static class members. So it's better never use them in the code like is written in post.

What about this specific example I would say push that values on collection, and check `meterNumber` makes a part of that collection, if you suspect that `999` will be not only number for this function, so condition satisfied.

There is also may be more complicated more OOP approach, like calling validation functions pushed on some `Stack` or `IEnumerable`, but I personally would avoid to introduce in my code that complexity only for reason to get rid from hardcoded values.

In short, my opinion is:  use constants, or conditional lists if there could be more then 1 value.